# Changing the style of the titles of "contents list" and "table of figures" makes those titles disppeared in table of contents

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, memoir

Using [psvectorian](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian?lang=en) package, I have defined a command as follows

```
\newcommand\setstyle[1]{\centering\Large\bfseries \psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\\[\baselineskip]#1\\[0.9\baselineskip]\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\\}
```

to change the styles of the titles of contents list and list of figures. However, those titles no longer appear in my contents list as shown below.

[image]

Given the following `MWE`, can you please propose a solution to this issue?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{psvectorian}

\newcommand\setstyle[1]{\centering\Large\bfseries \psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\\[\baselineskip]#1\\[0.9\baselineskip]\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\\}

\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}{\setstyle{Contents}}

\renewcommand{\printloftitle}{\setstyle{List of Figures}}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents    
    \listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \caption{my fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: They do appear, but you have redefined the names they used to be added to the TOC, `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}` etc so nothing appears

Comment: @daleif: Yes, but if I add anything to those empty arguments, I get unwanted titles underneath my defined style.

Comment: That is because you haven't correctly read the manual. `\printtoctitle` TAKES AN ARGUMENT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply because `\printtoctitle` and friends take an argument. You redefined it so it does not, thus the given argument is left over.

This works and is simpler than your attempt

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{psvectorian}

\newcommand\setstyle[1]{\centering\Large\bfseries
  \psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\\[\baselineskip]#1\\[0.9\baselineskip]\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\\}

\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\setstyle{#1}}
\renewcommand{\printloftitle}[1]{\setstyle{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents    
    \listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \caption{my fig}
\end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate you help.